# Trying to install Fabric test network but received just one container, How I can get the other containers? C:\Program Files\Git\var: Access is denied

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to install the Fabric test network and everything went well except for the container. It is supposed to have several containers like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFR8j.png)

However, I got just one container for the orderer as you can see here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP1ak.png)

Any help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Such kinds of docker issues can always happen when developing from windows OS. However, as for the solution to this issue, All we need to do is the following:

- CD: Fabric samples/test-network
- Open the (network.sh) script with any editor (e.g. Visual studio code)
- Setting the MSYS_NO_PATHCONV to 1 and adding it to the beginning of the (network.sh) script so that the script can be viewed as follow:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3y868.png)